# Repeated roots in ode

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for some help with the following question. I have determined the eigen value and it is a repeated root 
$$
x' = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -4& 4 \end{bmatrix}x
$$

One solution is

$$x^1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2  \end{bmatrix}e^{2t} $$

But now I am searching for the second solution. I have an idea for the second solution and I know it fails but I just want to see how it fails by plugging it back into the original $x'=ax $.

My guess is that

$$x^2 = \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \end{bmatrix}te^{2t} $$

So how do I plug that back into my original question to determine that $a=b=0? $

Comment: I just want to see how my guess is plugged back into the original, I am a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Just plug it in.  If $x = \left[ \matrix{a\cr b\cr} \right] t e^{2t}$, then $Ax = A \left[ \matrix{a\cr b\cr} \right] t e^{2t}$ while $x' =  \left[ \matrix{a\cr b\cr} \right]  e^{2t} + 2 \left[ \matrix{a\cr b\cr} \right] t e^{2t}$, and you have no way to cancel the $e^{2t}$ term unless $a=b=0$.

What you should try is
$$ x = \left[ \matrix{a\cr b\cr} \right] e^{2t} + \left[ \matrix{c\cr d\cr} \right] t e^{2t}$$

Comment: So what is A? And why cant you cancel term without being 0? Could you add more detail?

Comment: $A$ is the matrix $\left[ \matrix{0 & 1\cr -4 & 4\cr}\right]$.  The equation is $x' = A x$.  At $t=0$ the left side is $\left[ \matrix{a\cr b\cr} \right] $ and the right side is $0$.

Comment: So that's how you check if it doesn't work? Plug in 0 for t?